# Running prcomp() on 2D Data

Tags: r, image-processing, pca

I have a 3D Array that has the following dimensions: (24x24x100), in other words, images that are 24 by 24, and 100 of such images.

I would like to calculate the principal components of these images using R, however, I am having trouble running the `prcomp()` or even `princomp()` on this data. When I do run the functions like this: `prcomp(myArray)`, I only get one principal component (the output shows that I have 1 variable and 1000s observations, when I should have 24x24 variables and 100 observations).

What I would like to know is how can I use `prcomp()` or `princomp()` to find the principal components of my data.

For reference, my images are greyscale, so RGB depth does not matter.

Comment: You can resize the image array to a 100 x 576 matrix where each row represents an image and there are 24x24=576 columns for each image, each representing a pixel. Then do PCA on the matrix